# about putting inotify thread to sleep

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, kernel, inotify

I'm following [this example](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/04/getting-started-with-inotify/) to get notifications from the kernel for close events.

I wanted to add a small delay to the end of the while(1) loop to reduce the CPU usage. Will there be a chance to miss events, or will the kernel add the events not read by the program in the next iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to and, in fact, absolutely should not, introduce any extra latency into the notification loop.  CPU use should not be that high because the 'read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN )' call should block until something of interest happens.